# Why action will only be fired when MethodTest is exited?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await, webclient

`action.Invoke()` will not call the "action" Action until MethodTest is exited!

```
     private void MethodTest(string query)
     {
        try
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            string webContent = string.Empty;
            int index;
            Action action = async delegate()
            {
                webContent = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
                //Add break point above
            };

            action.Invoke();
            index = webContent.IndexOf("<div class=\"detName\">");
            // some code here
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Note: This would work fine!

```
     private async void MethodTest(string query)
     {
        try
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            string webContent = string.Empty;
            int index;
            webContent = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
            index = webContent.IndexOf("<div class=\"detName\">");
            // some code here
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since we can't set a breakpoint on a comment, is that meant to be "on the line above" or "on the line below" when you say "here"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action.Invoke` will invoke the delegate immediately. However, the delegate will not *complete* immediately, because it is asynchronous. The delegate will call `webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync` before `MethodTest` returns, but that's the only guarantee you have. In particular, it will *not* assign `webContent` before returning (unless your HTTP request is really, really fast).

It looks like you're trying to wrap asynchronous code in synchronous code. I don't want to say this is "doomed to fail", but it's certainly not a trivial endeavor.

The best solution is to allow your containing method to be `async`. I describe this in [my MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) as "async all the way".

If you're **absolutely sure** that you **need** to call asynchronous code from synchronous code, then [Stephen Toub has a good overview of the various approaches](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) (direct blocking, blocking on the thread pool, and nested message loops). There is no "best practice" in this scenario; every approach has disadvantages and pitfalls.